# How to reduce(improve) the execution of aggregate queries?

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB 3.2 version.
I have 4 core, 15GB ram.

I have 80 millions records, when I doing aggregate queries it's taking minimum 60 seconds to 100 seconds for each aggregate queries.
How to reduce the time? I have created for index also.

Please anyone give idea/suggest me.

Please refer sample document:

{
documentNo: "001230001",
collectedAmount: 143.23,
beginDate: "2015-05-23"
endDate: "2016-03-15",
vendorNumber: 123456,
vendorName: "ABC",
.
.
.
dept: 101,
year: 2016,
quarter: "Q1"
}

I have created indexes for "documentNo", "collectedAmount", "vendorNumber", "vendorName" "year"...etc

sample aggregate query:

**db.collection.aggregate([ { '$match': { documentNo: { '$regex': '123' } } }, { '$group': { _id: { documentNo: '$documentNo' }, Amount: { '$sum': '$collectedAmount' }, Count: { '$sum': 1 } } } ])**

Comment: You might need to provide the aggregate queries for us to make any comments whatsoever...

Comment: lack of info. What query do you do?

Comment: @NickBull ,evilive -- check my aggregate query.

Comment: You can use `explain()` on your query to check how the indices are used. Do the indices you created support your query? See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/ and [Mongo Indexing Strategies](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/indexes/).

Comment: I think your  `'$regex': '123'`  can be rather slow here... Do you want to check documents starting with 123 ? 
For instance `documentNo: { '$regex': /^123/ }`, which makes a better use of indexes if you have some (and you should).

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/ 
And like other said, check all indexes, and you can use projections to reduce data sent from server

Comment: @MateoBarahona, my documentNo is like thiss type **xxx123xxx**.

Comment: @karthickkumar : can you check how long it takes just to return documents matching `$regexp:'123'` ?

Comment: @MateoBarahona, **$match and $regexp** only taking 90 seconds.

Comment: @karthickkumar : 90 seconds ? You mean millis ? (it surprises me...). So aggregation taking 60/90 seconds for itself ??? I don't think there's much you can do then... Maybe try with Elasticsearch.

Comment: Why is your "collectedAmount" field string?

Comment: @MateoBarahona, No its in **Seconds**, but i want to improve in MongoDB only.

Comment: @JustLogin, collectedAmount is double only.

Comment: @karthickkumar : wait... So you're telling me it's taking 90 seconds ? Don't you think it's the main cause of the aggregation being slow ? Try aggregation without the match query ?

Comment: @MateoBarahona, i tried without **match** query also taking **65 to 99 seconds**. this is my query, 

**aggregate([  { '$group': { _id: { documentNo: '$documentNo' }, Amount: { '$sum': '$collectedAmount' }, Count: { '$sum': 1 } } } ])**